# objectWillChange do not update view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have ViewModel which looks like this:

```
class ItemsListViewModel : ObservableObject{

     var response : ItemsListResponse? = nil    
     var itemsList : [ListItem] = []    
     var isLoading = true    
     let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()


     func getItems() {
         self.isLoading = true

         ApiManager.shared.getItems()
        .sink(receiveCompletion: {completion in
        }, receiveValue: {               
            self.response = data   
            self.isLoading = false
            self.objectWillChange.send()                
        })    
   }
}
```

When I receive data from network request I use `self.objectWillChange.send()` to notify view, but view do not react to this.

My views :

**ItemsView**

```
struct ItemsView: View {      

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
           Text("Some Title")
           ItemsListView()
        }
    }
}
```

**ItemsListView**

```
struct ItemsListView: View {      
    @ObservedObject var myViewModel = ItemsListViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
           Text("\(self.myViewModel.response?.total")
        }.onAppear{
             self.myViewModel.getItems()                   
        }
    }
}
```

But the interesting thing, that if I use **ItemsListView** not inside 
 **ItemsView** everything works perfectly. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: you have to give itemsView the observedObject too so that SwiftUI knows that it has to update that view too

Comment: Have you tried to use @Published var response, instead of objectWillChange?

Comment: @Chris so how can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this ( i simplified just your model to test in playground)

you can copy directly the code in playground and check

```
struct Model {

    var items : [String]
}

class ItemsListViewModel : ObservableObject {

    @Published var items : [String] = ["Test 1", "Test2"]
}

let myViewModel = ItemsListViewModel()

struct ItemsView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
           Text("Some Title")
            ItemsListView().environmentObject(myViewModel)
        }
    }
}

struct ItemsListView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject private var model : ItemsListViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("\(model.items.count)")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ItemsView()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(myViewModel)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works. Can you explain why we should use `@EnvironmentObject` and pass it to child view from parent view?

Comment: check this please https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views

Answer (score 0):

Using @Published for properties of ObservableObject does fix your issue. See simplified below demo:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ItemsListViewModel : ObservableObject{

     @Published var response = ""
     var isLoading = true


     func getData() {
         self.isLoading = true

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            Just("test")
                .sink(receiveCompletion: {completion in
                }, receiveValue: { data in
                    self.response = data
                    self.isLoading = false
                })
        }
   }
}

struct ItemsListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var myViewModel = ItemsListViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
           Text("\(self.myViewModel.response)")
        }.onAppear{
             self.myViewModel.getData()
        }
    }
}

struct ItemsView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
           Text("Some Title")
           ItemsListView()
        }
    }
}

struct TestPublished: View {
    var body: some View {
        ItemsView()
    }
}

struct TestPublished_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestPublished()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it did not help. My view still do not updating

Comment: Then the problem is in other, absent, part of your code, because it works, even when I replaced in above example primitive String response with ItemsListResponse? struct.

Comment: As i said before, my code works when ItemsListView not inside ItemsView, i think the problem is that wrong view being notified